# How can I add a live Unity-style workspaces icon to the gnome-shell dock?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

I have configured gnome-shell in Ubuntu 18.04 to have 4 static workspaces in a grid with the "Workspace grid" gnome-shell extension.

I have also disabled the workspace overlay that pops up whenever you change workspaces with the "Disable workspace switcher popup" extension.

This provides an experience similar to what I had set up in Ubuntu 16.04.

However what I miss is the little workspaces icon that used to live in the Unity launcher. I rarely actually used this to change workspaces - instead I liked the fact that it had a little diagram of the workspace grid and showed which workspace you were on.

I can't find an equivalent for gnome-shell.

The closest kind of thing is the "Workspace indicator" extension but this only shows a number (ie "2") for the current workspace rather than a diagram, which is far less visually helpful. It is also in the top bar rather than the dock.

Is there anything out there that indicates workspace with a diagram? Ideally it would be able to live in the dock, but the top bar would be fine.

Thanks.